# Web Api take an array from front

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core-webapi

The question is very simple :-).
I'm a beginner.

Data comes to the controller (WebApi).
If you put an object.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder(Object [] orderR)


ValueKind = Object : "{"product":{"id":"72ae28f2-4ad3-4e97-5a7b- 
08d8db1aac26","code":"666666","name":"test6","price":6,"category":"test6","orrderItems":"320d57eb- 
3333-45d2-f497-08d8d66a0d39"},"quality":1}"

ValueKind = Object : "{"product":{"id":"72ae28f2-4ad3-4e97-5a7b- 
08d8db1aac26","code":"666666","name":"test6","price":6,"category":"test6","orrderItems":"320d57eb- 
3333-45d2-f497-08d8d66a0d39"},"quality":1}"

ValueKind = Object : "{"product":{"id":"72ae28f2-4ad3-4e97-5a7b- 
08d8db1aac26","code":"666666","name":"test6","price":6,"category":"test6","orrderItems":"320d57eb- 
3333-45d2-f497-08d8d66a0d39"},"quality":1}"
```

I created a class.

```
  public class OrderR
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public Guid orrderItems { get; set; }
    public string CODE { get; set; }
    public string NAME { get; set; }
    public int PRICE { get; set; }
    public string CATEGORY { get; set; }
    }
```

I am trying to get an array.

```
  [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder(OrderR[] orderR)
```

But get null.
What am I doing wrong?
How is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new class:

```
public class Order
    {
        public OrderR Product { get; set; }
        public int Quality { get; set; }
    }
```

and change your action to this:

```
 [HttpPost]
  public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder(Order[] orders)
{
  .... your code
}
```

it was tested in Postman using this data:

```
[
 {"product":{"id":"72ae28f2-4ad3-4e97-5a7b-08d8db1aac26","code":"666666","name":"test1","price":6,"category":"test6","orrderItems":"320d57eb-3333-45d2-f497-08d8d66a0d39"},"quality":1},

{"product":{"id":"72ae28f2-4ad3-4e97-5a7b-08d8db1aac26","code":"666666","name":"test2","price":6,"category":"test6","orrderItems":"320d57eb-3333-45d2-f497-08d8d66a0d39"},"quality":1},

{"product":{"id":"72ae28f2-4ad3-4e97-5a7b-08d8db1aac26","code":"666666","name":"test3","price":6,"category":"test6","orrderItems":"320d57eb-3333-45d2-f497-08d8d66a0d39"},"quality":1}
]
```

and everything works fine. If you want to test it in Postman too, add [FromBody] to the action input parameter:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrder([FromBody] Order[] orders)
        {
            return Ok(orders);
        }
```